# Unmet dependencies when installing libboost-all-dev on i386/debian Docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, debian, apt

I want to dockerize a build environment for Linux i386 targets. I need to install library dependencies such as boost. But I came across this error:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM i386/debian:sid
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install libboost1.67-all-dev
```

But even this simple script failed:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost1.67-all-dev : Depends: libboost-mpi1.67-dev but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libboost-mpi-python1.67-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed to `libboost1.67-dev` and it worked. I'm not sure what's the difference. If someone knows please explain that to me.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, I found two solutions:

- opt.1) `sudo apt install <unmet dependencies and sub-dependencies>`
  this is not straightforward but it should work
- opt.2) give up **all-dev** and install only required packages which may be like
  `sudo apt install build-essential:i386 libboost-system-dev:i386 libboost-thread-dev:i386 libboost-program-options-dev:i386 libboost-test-dev:i386`